# Select buildings of urban canyons from others buildings

Tags: qgis

I need to select all urban canyons with building shapes of the city.
Usually, urban canyon is some street with buildings on the both sides which create walls this "canyon". So problem in the following: it's necessary to select buildings having building in front of.

For example, there are clear urban canyons in the right side of the picture. But buildings in the lower left corner is the not urban canyons which should be removed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to postgis?

Answer (score 1):

To see the question in a different perspective, the general idea is that you want to select road links which have buildings on both sides (at a maximum given distance).
There are some ways to select those road links which come to mind, but the easiest one would be to:

1. Make sure each building has its own unique id (e.g. named `fid`). Create a non-dissolved buffer around building (say, with a radius of 10 or 20 meters);
2. Extract the self-overlapping portions (overlaps) of those buffers. Also here several ways, the easiest to understand is probably:

- `Processing Toolbox`->`Union`
- then open the Attribute Table
- create an integer virtual field named `overlap`
- input `if  ("fid" =  "fid_2", '0', '1' )` (where `fid` was the unique building ID)
- select only features with `overlap` = 1 (or, better, delete all features with `overlap` = 0)

3. Extract road links which are contained by those overlaps with `Processing Toolbox` -> `Clip`